# After editing detail record, wrong record is selected in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, detailsview

I have a GridView displaying several records.  Clicking on say the third record, displays a DetailsView below where I can edit the record.  If I make changes to the record and save, the GridView refreshes and resorts and now my edited record is the 5th row.  However, the 3rd row is still selected and the DetailsView now displays a different record than the one I just edited.

After an update via DetailsView, how do I make sure THAT record is reselected in the GridView no matter where it may now be in the GridView sort order?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the ID of each row by adding the field to the `DataKeyNames` of the GridView. Before you refresh the grid in code-behind, you remember the ID of the selected row (assuming here that the relevant ID is a field called ClientID):

```
int savedClientID = (int)gvClients.DataKeys[gvClients.SelectedIndex].Values["ClientID"];
```

You can then look for it after binding the data and select the corresponding row:

```
void gvClients_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvClients.SelectedIndex = -1;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvClients.Rows)
    {
        int clientID = (int)gvClients.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["ClientID"];

        if (clientID == savedClientID)
        {
            gvClients.SelectedIndex = row.RowIndex;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If paging is turned on in the GridView, you may have to use the method suggested in this post: [GridView in ASP.Net -- Selecting the correct row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355438/gridview-in-asp-net-selecting-the-correct-row)

Comment: I tried nearly the same solution, just a slight difference in how it loops.  Both this solution and the other work, as long as the record stars and ends on the same page of the GridView.  I have paged results in the GridView.  If the edited record goes from page 5 to page 1, a record on page 5 is selected instead of the edited record which is now on page 1.

Comment: I added a link to a post the could help you.